How to implement publishing and consuming messages in Kafka without delays
Tell me how to solve the problem in Kafka.
There is a consumer and a producer. Each of them is scaled to 6 copies. Both applications work with the same topic. There are 6 partitions in the topic.
The problem is that when a message is consumed from a partition, a long operation (3-5 minutes) is launched. And the message following it in the partition can wait a long time until the consumer finishes processing the current message, makes a commit and reads the next message from the partition. And the second message can no longer be processed in 3-5 minutes, but in 6-10 minutes, taking into account the wait in the queue. If there are even more messages in the queue, then the time increases accordingly for subsequent ones.
The first solution was to increase the number of partitions to 12 to reduce the problem, but I see 2 more problems in the work of publishers:

The publisher in the application publishes a message to the partition based on the hash, and not the round robin, and I don’t see the opportunity to set the configuration for the round robin (I see only consistent, random.. to choose from)
In the Kafka description, the round robin strategy itself works only within one instance of the publisher, and if the publisher’s application is scaled, then this strategy is not supported.

The question is: is it possible to somehow ensure that there is no lag in consuming a Kafka batch?

You are aware that waiting for commits is generally safety feature people want?  If you don't want to wait, just immediately commit or read many records at once and let your code pile them up asynchronously in some other work queue

First, a little bit of maths : if you have 10 messages per second, 1 consumer can spend 60/10=6s per message maximum in order to keep up with the messages. If you need to spend 180s (3 minutes) to process a message, then you need 30 (180s/6s) consumers.
Now if you want to distribute the processing, a solution is to have 1 instance of a consuming service and 30 instances of a processing service.The consuming service knows the 30 instances of the processing service (the 30 different URLs). The consuming service consumes the messages from the topic. For each message, it asks the first available processing service to process the message (API call) and marks the service as occupied. When the processing service responds, the consuming service marks it as available again. The hard part is to manage the commit of the messages, because you can have message at offset #10 processed before message at offset #9. You have to keep track of the last committed message and of the processed but uncommitted messages, and compute what offset to commit.


In the end I found a solution.
The point of the solution is to parallelize long message processing operations, running them in threads without awaiting.
After starting the tasks are added to a ConcurrentQueue or Channel and processed sequentially for committing to Kafka.
Hereunder code snippet.
var locker = new SemaphoreSlim(subscribeOptions.MaxParallelTasksCount);
                    var tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<(Task task, ConsumeResult<string, string> result)>();
                    var consumerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            if (tasks.TryDequeue(out var task))
                            {
                                await task.task;
                                consumer.Commit(task.result);
                                locker.Release();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            await locker.WaitAsync();
                            try
                            {
                                var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
                                try
                                {
                                    
                                    var processing = ProcessEventAsync<T, TH>(consumeResult.Message);
                                    tasks.Enqueue((processing, consumeResult));
                                }
...

As I wrote you could use Channel with Writer and Reader for async consuming of internal queue.
